# Handle ftp_put warnings in PHP 4

Tags: php, php4

In an ideal world I would use a try/catch block to handle warnings from ftp_put, but sadly I have to use PHP 4 for legacy reasons, which does not have this. I am handling the basic true/false with an IF as below. Does anyone know how to handle warnings from this?

```
if (ftp_put($connection, $fileName, $file, FTP_ASCII)){
    //tell them it worked
}else{
   //fail
}
```

Comment: You can suppress warnings by appending @ such as `@ftp_put(...)` although we all know this to be a bit hacky... still using PHP4 is worse IMO ;)

Comment: I'd rather log some useful info if I can rather than just suppress it. That would be last resort.

Comment: Oh, well in that case you'll have to apply Display Errors: http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors in theory if you have a custom error handler for logging you'll still get them logged but you won't see them outputted.